# Vertically stack an array of buttons using auto layout VFL

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm learning auto layout and I'd like to setup a set of buttons to be vertically stacked and evenly spaced. I'd also like the buttons pinned to the bottom of the view. What's a good way to setup these constraints with VFL? The button list will be passed in as an array of UIButtons.

```
NSArray *buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, ...]
NSMutableArray *allConstraints = [NSMutableArray array]
UIButton *previousButton;

for (UIButton button in buttons) {
    // Buttons take up full width 
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[button]|"
                                options:0
                                metrics:nil
                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button);];
    [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[button]|"
                                options:0
                                metrics:nil
                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button);];
    [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];

    if (!previousButton) {
        NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding" : @(10)};

        // Make buttons height
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[-(padding)-previousButton(==button)]"
                                                              options:0
                                                              metrics:metrics
                                                                views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousButton, button)];
        [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];
    }
    previousButton = button;
}

[self.view addConstraints:allConstraints]
```

This doesn't achieve what I need as the buttons don't get pinned to the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this might help you out

```
NSArray *buttons = @[button1, button2, button3, button4, button5];
NSMutableArray *allConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];
UIButton *previousButton;

for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
    [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    // Buttons take up full width
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[button]|"
                            options:0
                            metrics:nil
                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)];
    [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];
    if (!previousButton) {
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|->=10-[button(65)]"
                   options: 0
                   metrics:nil
                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)];
                [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];
    }
    if (previousButton) {
        NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding" : @(10)};

        // Make buttons height
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousButton]-(20)-[button(65)]"
                                                              options:0
                                                              metrics:metrics
                                                                views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousButton, button)];
        [allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];
    }
    previousButton = button;
}
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousButton]-10-|"
                        options:0
                        metrics:nil
                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousButton)];
[allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:allConstraints]
```

Comment: With button(65), are you telling that the button can be no smaller than that height value? Is there a way to automatically configure that, without hard coding it?

Comment: HI @WillamHill, yes with button(65) i am fixing its height. If you prefer not to, it is possible to do that as well. If you don't specify the height then a button with text will take height as 30 and if button is a image it will resize itself as required

Answer (score 5):

I would do it in a somewhat different way. Rather than building up the constraints inside a loop, I would build the format string in a loop.

```
-(void)addButtonsWithConstraints:(NSArray *) buttons {
    NSMutableDictionary *views = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (int i = 0; i<buttons.count; i++) {
        [buttons[i] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
        [self.view addSubview:buttons[i]];
        [views setObject:buttons[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%d",i]];
    }

    NSMutableString *formatString = [@"V:" mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i<buttons.count-1; i++) {
        [formatString appendFormat:@"[button%d]-10-", i];
    }
    [formatString appendFormat:@"[button%lu]|", buttons.count - 1]; // pins the last button to the bottom of the view
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatString options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[button0]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
```

The last line sets button0 to the full width of the view, and the format options in the previous line make all the buttons align their left and right edges.

Comment: Remember to check if array is empty!