# How to make constraints (auto-layout) work programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints

This is my very first iOS project, and as such i am having difficulty with constraints and auto-layout.

Here is what i am trying to do. I want to add Subviews to a UIScrollView. This i am doing programmatically as the number of subviews are not static. I can make auto-layout and constraints work perfectly when i am just adding a single subview (in code or XIB), or multiple subviews through XIB. But i am having trouble making it work with a dynamic number of subviews in code.

The numerous instances of the subview gets created, but they are all on top of each other as constraints doesn't work. I want them to lineup under each under, which is why im trying to make constraints work. (For now i have just set the number of subviews to 10, this is just temporary though)

Here is some of my code (starting with the press of a button):

```
-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender {

UIScrollView *matchScrollView = (UIScrollView *) [self.view viewWithTag:1];
NSMutableArray *matchViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    MatchView *newMatchView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MatchView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    [matchViewsArray addObject:newMatchView];
}

for (int i = 0; i < [matchViewsArray count]; i++) {
    MatchView *newMatchView = matchViewsArray[i];

//I kept some IBOutlets out of the code example here. They work fine with a single subview. or even multiple subviews as long as you don't mind they are all on top of each other due to constraints not working xD
    [newMatchView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [matchScrollView addSubview:matchViewsArray[i]];

    [matchScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:matchScrollView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:8.0]];

    [matchScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:matchScrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:8.0]];

    //If this is not the first object, then the top of the object contraints with the bottom of the previous object
    if (i > 0) {
        // I think the fault may lie here. Do i need to remove the previous constraint, or will it be overwritten? This did not work however, did i remove it wrong?

        //Making sure it only tries to call removeconstraint: once and once only, as the constraint is only put on the else statement which only executes on the very first object. Attempt to fix the code
        if (i == 1) {
        [matchScrollView removeConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i - 1]
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:matchScrollView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:8.0]];
        }

        [matchViewsArray[i - 1] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:matchViewsArray[i - 1]
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:8.0]];
    }

    //The top of the first object constraints with the top of the matchScrollView
    else {
        [matchScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:matchScrollView
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:8.0]];
    }

    //If this is the last object, then the bottom of the object constraints with the bottom of matchScrollView
    if ( i == [matchViewsArray count] - 1) {
        //tried removing the constraint created by else statement first before adding a new constraint
        [matchViewsArray[i] removeConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i - 1]
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                                            constant:8.0]];

        [matchScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                                       toItem:matchScrollView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:8.0]];
    }
    //else the bottom of the object contraints with the top of the next object
    else {
        [matchViewsArray[i + 1] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:matchViewsArray[i + 1]
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:8.0]];
    }

    [matchScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:matchViewsArray[i]
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:matchScrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0.0]];
}
```

}

I keep getting "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". I tried removing old constraints before adding new ones, which didn't help. Unless i am removing them wrong?

If i remove all the if and else statements, and just create a single Subview, then the constraints work perfectly. if i create multiple subviews, then the app doesn't crash, but the subviews all have the same constraints and are on top of each other. So by adding the if and else statements and working with matchViewsArray[i - 1] i tried setting the constraints for multiple subviews.

Besides, even if this code works, is there really no easier way of doing this instead of all this if and else statements inside a loop?

As said, this is my very first iOS project, so there are probably more efficient and better ways to implement the behaviour i want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Quick tip 1: set exception breakpoint in Xcode breakpoints tab to catch them before losing the context. (oops didn't see 2nd is already there).

Comment: I think it's much easier to use the visual format language to build your constraints. Instead of adding all the constraints in a loop, I would build up the format string in a loop. Look at my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769481/vertically-stack-an-array-of-buttons-using-auto-layout-vfl/28770327#28770327, for how I've done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I have no license to make iOS apps and cannot test it as-is, but this OSX snippet may help:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSView *contentView = [window contentView];

    NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
        [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", (int)pow(10, i)]];
        [button setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
        [button setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSize]]];
        [button sizeToFit];

        [buttons addObject:button];
        [contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    int count = (int)[buttons count];

    // 1. one below other
    // 2. all equal width

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        NSView *view1 = buttons[i-1];
        NSView *view2 = buttons[i];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2);

        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view1]-[view2]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];
        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[view1(==view2)]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];
    }

    // 3. first -> top

    if (count > 0) {
        NSView *view = [buttons firstObject];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);

        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[view]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];
    }

    // 4. last -> bottom

    if (count > 0) {
        NSView *view = [buttons lastObject];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);

        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view]-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];
    }

    // 5. left <- all -> right

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSView *view = buttons[i];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);

        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[view]-(>=20)-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views]];
    }
}
```

[image: What it looks like]

Note that you can't specify default 8/20 spacings without using "visual format language", because `constraintsWithVisualFormat:...` produces special constraints (well, with special private flags inside) that auto-resize 8 under specific circumstances to 6/4/whatever accordingly to Apple's HIG. (You may try placing controls in IB and see that default is not always 8, but at runtime it suddenly is!).

**edit:** Also, you may always use simple #define or a subroutine to hide that [[[content-constraint-with-contraint-visual-constraint-with-constraints-ponies]]] ladder.

**edit2:** Refactoring phase :)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is much more simple and elegant, which hurts my brain less! It works perfectly so far! Now i know this method for the future, instead of the way i initially tried to make it xD